# Change Markers icon onMap click

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Hello I'm making the google maps app, in my app in add the features of area measurement, in area measurement the user click on the map and the marker are set on pointing areas if user point the seven places then the seven markers are set on pointing places but I change the marker icons on every point but the icon are never change please help me to change the marker icons on every click

```
 My code is

     public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;
            marker = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker);
            pointaa = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pointaa);
            pointb = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pointb);

            changeView(getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .getInt("mapView", GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL));

            mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker clickcount) {

                    marker = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker);
                    pointaa = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pointaa);
                    pointb = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pointb);
                    addPoint(clickcount.getPosition());

                    return true;
                }
            });



            mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMapClick(final LatLng center) {
                    clickcounter=clickcounter+1;
    if (clickcounter==1){
        if (marker!=null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            marker = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker);

        }



    }if (clickcounter==2){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        pointaa = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pointaa);
                        addPoint(center);


                    }if (clickcounter==3){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"3",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        pointb = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pointb);
                        addPoint(center);

                    }

                }
            });


      private Marker drawMarker(final LatLng center) {
            return mMap.addMarker(
                    new MarkerOptions().position(center).flat(true).anchor(0.5f, 0.5f).icon(pointb).icon(pointaa).icon(marker));

        }
```

Comment: In this code only the .icon(marker) are set the other 2 icons are not set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Below code

```
  mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I am using if else statement e.g
if 
        if (clickcount==1){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
            and the result is the markers are overridden. The default marker is appear and custom marker are appear on the back of default marker,i want to change every single marker on every on map click

Comment: this solution is working but the only one color is change i want to change the 2 or 3 colors

Comment: @HassanAliMughal i did not got you point can you please Explain in detail what's the exact issue.?

Comment: @MayurRajvir My point is:- i using the switch statement to use the color of marker there are 8 colors of marker are in map and i use the clickcounter, if i click the 9 click on map the default color are set on 9 marker and never change the 10 and 10 + marker color

Comment: means the 8 color are change but the 9 or 9 +color are not change

Answer (score 0):

You can change the marker icon as below.

```
Marker marker = new MarkerOptions().position(center).flat(true).anchor(0.5f, 0.5f);
BitmapDescriptor descriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker); 
   // Changing marker icon
marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_marker_icon)));
```